# Can I set up a git respository on a home server? (If so how?)

Tags: git

My understanding of git is basic, however I understand that a project can be "pushed" from one system to a remote system, from where it can be cloned or pulled by others to other computers.

For example, I understand that github.com is one domain where projects can be pushed to, or can be hosted.

My question is, can I set up a github like repository on a home server, to which I can then push backups of my work to, assuming that I know relevant information such as the servers IP, etc, etc.

If the answer to this question is "yes", then question number 2 is "how?".

Edit: I think I might actually be wanting to use a SVN system, not a Git one for this?

Comment: @self What makes you think I am employed?

Answer (score 3):

If you can SSH into your home server, it’s as easy as making a folder (with some stuff inside it)!

```
[user@remote ~]$ mkdir my-project
[user@remote ~/my-project]$ cd my-project/
[user@remote ~/my-project]$ git init --bare
```

and

```
[me@local ~/my-project]$ git remote add home-server ssh://user@remote/my-project
```

This creates a bare remote repository, which is essentially the same as the `.git` folder in your local one.

Comment: Hi, I think I have misunderstood. I thought SSH was a protocol used to connect securely to a terminal such as bash through a remote connection? I'm not understanding the relevance of it here. Surely I don't have to use SSH? I want to use git to handle the transfers, and use it to back up copies of my work to a home server from another home computer. A bit like using push and pull to move files to and from a github repository?

Comment: @user3728501: It is, but have you used scp, for example? SSH is the most convenient way to set this up. If you tend to use https://\* origins with GitHub, a) that’s much harder to do, and b) I’d recommend you stop and use SSH for that too.

Comment: I was sort of thinking that I would setup some git software on a networked machine with a static IP and do something like 'git push something somewhere', where possibly somewhere is something like "192.168.0.X". Not sure if that helps clarify what I'm trying to do? I only have a vague idea about how I might go about it at the moment.

Comment: @user3728501: Again, if it’s just you, the easiest way to do that is make the bare repository on the remote and add `ssh://user@192.168.0.X/path/to/bare/repository` as a remote. If you’d like to try it, though, there’s software like [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) and [Gogs](https://github.com/gogits/gogs) available.

Comment: @user3728501 this is totally what you're looking for, man.  Once you have this set up, you will just `git add .`, `git commit`, `git push origin master` and all your stuff is backed up.

Answer (score 0):

Question number 1: yes, you can, git is a distributed version control system.

Question number 2: what O.S. are you running on your server? Windows? Linux? If you have linux then you can (and should) consider using SSH on your server, depending on your distro you will find several tutorials of how to set up the SSH server on the web, this is one i've used myself with ubuntu

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html

If you have windows, you can test this:

http://www.redeszone.net/windows/freesshd-para-windows-instalacion-y-manual-de-configuracion-de-freesshd-para-windows-servidor-ssh-y-sftp/

And if you can't translate the page (the last one is in spanish) you can read this discussion about SSH servers on windows:

https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows

I don't have personal experience with a SSH server on windows, but i do use Putty as client.

So, in order to access (securely) to your remote git repository you have to access through SSH.

**EDIT:**

Well, everybody suggest you to use SSH but you don't know why, i'll try to explain what i know or what i think i know.

Git is not like SVN, you don't have and program/process running as server, you don't connect with a "Git server" to make a push.

Imagine that you have 2 copies of your project versioned with Git on your local computer, let's name those copies A and B, you can configure "remotes" on A or B to push to one or the other, but that's done by a single program (Git), when you run the command to push, Git should have access to BOTH repositories, then he makes all the checks needed and persist the data on the appropiate repository.

When you have a repository on a remote server, you can still use git to make a push but you need to give Git a way to access the remote repository (as it was local), and you can use protocols like ftp, and here is when SSH get in action, with SSH you can use SCP and/or SFTP, (a way to access your repository with a secure connection).

You can also set up a VPN and share the container folder (of projects) over the network and mount that folder as it was local (if you are the only one accesing the files, if you are working with a team then you should use SSH (scp/sftp)).

But the best way to do it by far is using SSH, you should try it.

Comment: Hi Yes I am using Linux

Comment: Take a look at this page [SSH Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-to-connect-to-a-remote-server-in-ubuntu) to learn about SSH if you don't know anything about it, it will give you a basic understanding of how SSH work.

Comment: Is SSH what I really want to be using? I thought SSH was just a method of accessing remote shells (like bash?) securely?

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried the same thing on my machine just to understand Git workflow. I personally prefer to use git code hosting sites. Here is how I had done this,

```
$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
```

For security purpose, create a new user account for git,

```
$ sudo adduser git
$ su git
$ cd
$ mkdir .ssh && chmod 700 .ssh
$ touch .ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now, let's say your friend John is working with you and you want to give him access to your user account git. So, copy his public key to git user's file: `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

To generate ssh private-public key pair on your friend's machine use the following command,

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Now create a directory accessible by user git, e.g.: `/opt/git/project.git`

```
$ cd /opt/git/project.git
$ git init --bare
```

Now, John can push changes done in his local machine to your git server.

```
$ cd myproject
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'initial commit'
$ git remote add origin git@gitserver:/opt/git/project.git
$ git push origin master
```

I think, these are the basic steps you wanted. You can find more details [on git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server).
The same link also explains how to restrict git user to only doing Git activities with a limited shell tool called `git-shell`.

Comment: I think this might be along the lines of what I want but why all the requirement for SSH? Can't it be done without?

My guess is that the 2 key lines are 'git remote add origin <blaa>', which I GUESS tells git that it should treat any keyword 'origin' as what ever is in place of '<blaa>' - which in this case is 'git@gitserver:/opt/git/project.git'...

And the second key line being 'git push origin master' which I guess moves the changed files from 'master' (which to git means current directory?) to 'origin' which has previously been declared to be the above web address. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, you can also do this without ssh, but in that, shared access is more difficult. So I think you are looking for [local protocol method] (http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#Local-Protocol)